# Compare div elements to a date and move them into another div

Tags: jquery

I have a div element (**#receivedInfo**) with p elements inside of it. Each p element has a date in it. I managed to take out this date from each element and compare it to the current date.
After I compare each element to the current date, I want to move them in two divs:

- one to contain all elements that have a date higher than the current date ("**.licitatiiActive**")
- the other to contain all the elements that have a lower date than the current date ("**.licitatiiInactive**")

I managed to do the comparison, but all I can move is only one element.

Here is the HTML I use:

```
<div id="receivedInfo" class="hidden">
    <p>16.10.2012 - <a href="#">test line 1</a></p>
    <p>16.10.2012 - <a href="#">test line 2</a></p>
    <p>16.10.2012 - <a href="#">test line 3</a></p>
    <p>16.10.2012 - <a href="#">test line 4</a></p>
</div>
<div class="licitatiiActive"></div>
<div class="licitatiiInactive"></div>
```

And here is the jQuery I use:

```
var fullDate = new Date();
var twoDigitMonth = (fullDate.getMonth()+1)+"";
if(twoDigitMonth.length==1) twoDigitMonth="0" +twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate()+"";
if(twoDigitDate.length==1)  twoDigitDate="0" +twoDigitDate;
var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "." + twoDigitMonth + "." + fullDate.getFullYear();

var dataLic;
var infoP;

$.each($("#receivedInfo p"), function () {
    var info = $(this).html();
    dataLic = info.split(' - ')[0].trim();
    infoP = "<p>" + info + "</p>";

});
if (dataLic > currentDate) {
        $(".licitatiiInactive").html(infoP);
    } else {
        $(".licitatiiActive").html(infoP);
    }
```

As mentioned, the result is that only the first p element from div "**#receivedInfo**" is being moved to the div "**.licitatiiInactive**".
How can I adjust this script to move each element of "**#receivedInfo**" to the proper div?

Comment: @Tats_innit i believe there is a misunderstanding. My suggested edit is neither incorrect nor  an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post. I wanted to change the dates because it makes it easier to spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Relevant part outside loop and same sample date

I was astonished at first since my debug attempt with [chrome dev tools](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) and a console.log  showed the same date every time. The  reason was that every sample date was / is the same.

Below you can see a working solution. The var dataLic is filled in the each-loop and its current value is handled by appendDate.

```
$.each($("#receivedInfo p"), function () {              
    dataLic = $(this).html().split(' - ')[0].trim();                
    console.log("dataLic", dataLic, "currentDate", currentDate);        
    appendDate(dataLic, currentDate);
});

function appendDate(dataLic, currentDate){
    if (dataLic > currentDate) {
        $(".licitatiiInactive").append(dataLic +"<br/>");
    } else {
        $(".licitatiiActive").append(dataLic+"<br/>");
    }   
}
```

### Update bug found and sample online

It was quite simple to find the bug after i changed the sample dates.
You are looping over each date with  `$.each` but your code to copy the values is outside the loop. If you put your code (see my `function appendDate()`) inside the loop every single value will be handled and not just the last one.
Please take a look at a [working solution to copy the elements](http://jsfiddle.net/eTgYM/)

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me where the problem was. I just made a minor change so that I can take the entire paragraph and not just the date but it works great! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad i could help. Please take a look at my suggested edit of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/898286 I believe it would be good if in your question the dates would vary.

Comment: I used the same date, as it is a major part in what I try to achieve. There will be around 20-30 entries with the same date so that is why I used a single date for all entries :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each pass of the `each` loop overwrites the variable `infoP` and you aren't trying to move the html until after the `each` has been completed.

Instead you want to check the date within each pass of the loop and append the new html string.

EDIT  Date logic can be simplified and cleaned up by comparing 2 date objects as this code shows

**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/8ngA5/2/

```
var fullDate = new Date();

$("#receivedInfo p").each(function() {
    var info = $(this).html();
    var dataLic = $.trim(info.split(' - ')[0]).split('.');

    var d=new Date(parseInt( dataLic[2]), parseInt( dataLic[1]), parseInt( dataLic[0]))


    var infoP = "<p>" + info + "</p>";

    if (d < fullDate) {
        $(".licitatiiInactive").append(infoP);
    } else {
        $(".licitatiiActive").append(infoP);
    }

});
```

Comment: I have tried this version as-well, still no luck. Only the first p element is being moved :(

Comment: my code works fine, however your data methodolgy isn't going to work

Comment: @inadcod Since you are using the just one sample date it may appear that way. Please accept my edit changes and you will see

Comment: OK... I greatly simplified your date logic and gave you a working demo

Answer (score 1):

modify your script as follows:

```
    var fullDate = new Date();
    var twoDigitMonth = (fullDate.getMonth()+1)+"";
    if(twoDigitMonth.length==1) twoDigitMonth="0" +twoDigitMonth;
    var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate()+"";
    if(twoDigitDate.length==1)  twoDigitDate="0" +twoDigitDate;
    var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "." + twoDigitMonth + "." + fullDate.getFullYear();

    var dataLic;
    var infoP;

    $.each($("#receivedInfo p"), function () {
        var info = $(this).html();
        dataLic = info.split(' - ')[0].trim();
        infoP = "<p>" + info + "</p>";
        if (dataLic > currentDate) {
            $(".licitatiiInactive").append(infoP);
        } else {
            $(".licitatiiActive").append(infoP);
        }        
    });
```

Comment: using `html()` method to add to element content will end up with same result as OP code since it replaces the html of the element each time. Use `append()` instead

Comment: @charlietfl didn't noticed that .. :)

Comment: I have tried using append() but it still gets only the first p element :(